Wired clients cannot connect to each other on home LAN
I have (what I thought was) a simple home LAN setup. I'm using an Asus RT-AXE7800 router which has the following clients (the IP addresses have been fixed for convenience).



Machine
OS
LAN Access
IP Address




Raspberrypi
Raspbian
wired
xxx.xxx.xxx.5


AMD64 server
Debian
wired
xxx.xxx.xxx.9


AMD64 desktop
Windows
wired
xxx.xxx.xxx.20


AMD64 laptop
Windows
wifi 6&5GHz
xxx.xxx.xxx.3



The AMD64 laptop can ping and connect - e.g. via Samba/SMB or ssh - to any of the other machines. Any of the other machines can connect to the AMD64 laptop e.g. the raspberrypi can mount a windows share on the AMD64 laptop from its command line using the samba client . Ssh and ftp works both ways also. What is not possible is for the Raspberrypi, AMD64 server and AMD64 desktop to communicate with each other. I've tried pings, samba, ssh, ftp but nothing works.
The only pattern, if you will, that I can see here is as follows: when a wifi-connected client attempts to connected to a wired-connected client it works. However wired-to-wired communication seems not to be possible. To further verify this thesis, the AMD64 windows desktop has a wifi adapter so I removed the ethernet cable, connected to the wifi network and this time, like with the laptop, it was able to connect to the wired clients.
[While the fact that connectivity is possible between a wifi and wired machines suggests this isn't a firewall issue, during my research I disabled the firewalls on the two linux machines.]
It feels like I'm missing something very basic. Why can't wired clients connect to each other over a simple home network?

it looks like a classic "port isolation" scenario. The principle behind port isolation in professional networks is to disallow some (or all) of the hosts to communicate with each other on so called "layer 2" - without using the router (where we can i.e. monitor traffic).
The problem is I can't find any option for it in your device's official user guide. It's easy to find for the wireless interface:

but not for the wired. Assuming all of your clients reside in the same vlan check the following items:

Advanced Settings -> LAN -> LAN IP: check if your subnet mask ends with ".0",
General -> Network Map -> Client status: check for any weird options,
General -> AiProtection: check if it's enabled, if so - check if any of your LAN hosts is detected,
Advanced Settings -> Firewall -> General: check if there are any rules applied to the LAN interfaces,
Advanced Settings -> Firewall -> Network Service Filter: same check as above,
Advanced Settings -> System Log: check for suspicious entries (like that something from the LAN was dropped).

The guide I used to <try ;]> to help you is quite simple, so I encourage you to click through every configuration option on the device - you may find something that wasn't mentioned in the guide. Feel free to ask if you find anything you'd like explained ;]
Regards
Mike

@AdamGold
/27 means 32 hosts - so the problem lies elsewhere (considering IP's you posted are real). Your proposed change should be possible, sure. But I'd look for the actual problem first if I were you. Have you checked the logs? Is device firmware updated? Finally - you can always try factory reset. To be honest, for the 15+ years working as a network/systems engineer I've NEVER EVER seen that exact behavior in a soho router.

@AdamGold  sure, why not. Consider me intrigued enough ;]

@AdamGold I am not clear from the comments if all the devices have identical subnet masks now? They need to.
